# The font size shrinks on Gmail app (email template issue)

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, email-templates

I am facing a weird issue while building an email template.

I have to place two images side by side on both Desktop and Mobile view. The template works perfectly on Yahoo Mail both on Desktop and Mobile view, but in Gmail Mobile App the template is being resized.

You can see in the below screenshots the font size shrinks in Gmail
App. That is the main issue.

**First image is of Yahoo Mobile App**, which works perfectly.

[image: Yahoo App View]

**Second one is Gmail Mobile App**, which is creating issues.

[image: Gmail App View]

What can I try next?

Here is the code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <!-- LEFT IMAGE GOES HERE -->
        <td valign="top" width="50%" class="img trnd-mobb-td1" style="" align="left">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="thumb1" style="" align="left">

                        <div class="fluid-img" style="" align="center">
                            <a href="https://www.dummy.com/" target="_blank" style="">
                                <img class="subarticle-img" border="0" src="https://media.sailthru.com/1gg/1k5/a/o/6176392b5e7cc.jpeg" alt="This Is Not a Drill: 6 Products for a More Even Skin Tone"  height=""  />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        
        <!-- RIGHT IMAGE GOES HERE -->
        <td valign="top" class="img trnd-mobb-td2" style="" align="left">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="thumb" style="" align="left">

                        <div class="fluid-img" style="" align="center">
                            <a href="https://www.dummy.com/" target="_blank" style="">
                                <img class="subarticle-img" border="0" src="https://media.sailthru.com/1gg/1k5/a/o/6176393723c2b.jpeg" alt="This Is Not a Drill: 6 Products for a More Even Skin Tone"  height=""  />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can't help you but tell you that e-mail templating is a pain in the a.. and you might not be able to have it perfectly the same on all e-mail clients.

Comment: Have you tried putting all styling inline? And what is the styling of the img and its parent?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, it didn't work. Actually the issue is with the images, If I place images in two different rows then it works fine. But as I described above I need to place images Side by Side. Yahoo works well, don't know what's wrong with Gmail

Comment: Just set the table/content width in pixels, or add inline margin to one of your images if you want space in between them and eventually fluid design.

Comment: @skobaljic The issue is with the Font Size, you can see in Gmail App, the font shrinks. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @skobaljic I have updated my question to make it more clear, the issue is with the Font Size, it is shrinking in Gmail. I want to get rid of that. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: You haven’t told us the CSS you are using, but this is a question about styling and the emphasis has changed from the imgs to the font size so I think we need to see the CSS and how you are applying it.

Comment: You gotta understand, for html emails you have to put all of your styles also inline with elements (table, table rows, images) - specially font size. Do not use paragraphs - use breaks etc. Your html email should have all styles applied without `<style>...</style>` - those you put later in there should be for fluid layout mainly. You should really explore more html emails, or take one you think is fine, than edit it. The way you did is not compatible to many email clients. More than that, some email clients won't load images by default, so your template should look ok with no images loaded.

Comment: You have not given any  width or height for your image. Try controlling it with media queries to see if it works. You have class but you have not posted any CSS with it. Can you post that as well so its easy to troubleshoot?

Comment: @skobaljic you can use paragraphs, just make margin and padding 0;